# Why is Tomcat not scaling throughput with increased concurrent load?

Tags: tomcat8

For this test, I have a simple Java servlet that reads data in and calculates the CRC32 for it.  When making serial requests of 512MB each, I get about 600MB/sec.  That makes sense since I can't use all 24 cores available to me to calculate a CRC.  The program driving this I/O is sitting on the local box to eliminate the possibility of networking issues.  I am running Tomcat 8.0.24.0 on FreeBSD using OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode).

Next, I attempt the same test with 6 concurrent requests, expecting that the performance per request might be lower than 600MB/sec, but that the aggregate performance across all 6 requests would be significantly higher.

What I see is the CPU has some idle time at ALL times (so it doesn't appear that I'm CPU-bound).  I also see that all processing threads in Tomcat are running concurrently as anticipated.  However, it looks like I'm only getting around 800MB/sec in aggregate.  The threads in Tomcat spend most of their time waiting to read from the socket, as shown below.

I would appreciate any thoughts on how to improve Tomcat throughput / why so much time is spent waiting for more data (which I assume is what's going on below).

```
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1037)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.tryAcquireSharedNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1328)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$KeyAttachment.awaitLatch(NioEndpoint.java:1386)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$KeyAttachment.awaitReadLatch(NioEndpoint.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:185)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:251)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:232)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer.fill(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:133)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalNioInputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(InternalNioInputBuffer.java:177)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractInputBuffer.doRead(AbstractInputBuffer.java:416)
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:342)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:190)
```

...